# Exploiting buffer overflow leads to segfault

Tags: buffer-overflow, c

I am trying to exploit simple stack overflow vulnerability. I have a basic code in c:

```
#include <cstring>
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
        char buffer[500];
        strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

compiled using `-fno-stack-protector`. I've already figured out the buffer length and I've successfully overwritten the EBP and EIP registers. I injected a large number of NOPs, followed with [this shell code](https://gist.github.com/tsusanka/f55fbf6ad6429473e546) and finally inserted an address where the injected NOPs are so the code is executed.

Now the problem. On the picture attached you can see the gdb output. If I run my program with malicious input it gets a SIGSEGV. Dumping the address `0xbffff880` you can see there is a lot of NOPs followed with the shell code (pink box) and finally with the address (blue box).

I've thought this would work as follows: At first the `0x90909090`s and the shellcode are considered as simple data. After these (past the pink box) there is an address `0xbffff880`. I am saying to the cpu "hey there, now please execute what's on `0xbffff880`". The cpu takes what's on the address and executes all the NOPs and the shellcode itself. However that's not happening and SIGSEGV occures.

Where am I mistaken?

[image: gdb output]

I am trying to achieve this on Virtualbox instance of 32-bit Ubuntu 14.04 Linux 3.13.0-39-generic i686 with ASLR turned off.

Comment: Are you on x64?  x86?  OS you're on?

Comment: Thx for the note, see the bottom of the question.

Comment: I would guess that the memory at `0xbffff880` is not marked as executable.  Try changing the permissions with [mprotect](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23618&seqNum=10).

Comment: Indeed! I was searching a bit around and found out that compiling using `-z execstack` should as well solve this. I recompiled my code with that flag and it really does work! Great, thanks a lot. I consider this as proof of concept, so I am satisfied with that solution :). Btw do i understand it right that if I liked to ommit the `-z execstack` I use the mprotect code and append it to my shell code? What about that `-fno-stack-protect..` are there ways to exploit buffer overflow even with stack protection on?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your memory address `0xbffff880` is most likely non-executable, but only read/write.  There are a couple of ways you can overcome this.

1. If that is a stack address you can use `-z execstack` while compiling.  This will essentially make the entire stack memory executable.
2. For a more robust solution you can write the shellcode to call [mprotect](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=23618&seqNum=10) on the address you are writing to.

For example, the following line will mark address `0xbffff880` as read/write/executable.

`mprotect((void*) 0xbffff880, buffer_len, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC);`

[`-fno-stack-protector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10713047/3714897) does not mean that the stack will be executable.  It only disables other security features such as canaries or [stack cookies](https://www.corelan.be/index.php/2009/09/21/exploit-writing-tutorial-part-6-bypassing-stack-cookies-safeseh-hw-dep-and-aslr/). If these values are overwritten (with a buffer overflow) when they are checked the program will fail.  This would *not* enable the execution of your buffer.

Answer (score 3):

As RoraZ said, your stack is not executable. To expand on that, buffer overflow exploit like that will not work on a modern linux box unless the binary is compiled to allow such shenanigans. You will need to disable a number of security features; RELRO, STACK CANARY, NX, PIE.

There is a nice bash script called checksec.sh (http://www.trapkit.de/tools/checksec.html) that can help you check the binary, for example:

[image]

The way I compile a binary for x86 buffer overflow test:

```
gcc -m32 -g -mpreferred-stack-boundary=2 -no-pie -fno-stack-protector -Wl,-z,norelro -z execstack ./program.c
```

1. -no-pie: disable PIE (position independent executable)
2. -z execstack: to disable NX (making stack executable)
3. -Wl,-z,norelro: disable RELRO (readonly relocations)
4. -fno-stack-protector: remove stack protection (stack overflow security checks)

And for convenience:

-g: add debugging

-mpreferred-stack-bounary=2: align stack on 4-byte boundary